# Framework similar to vert.x for .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vert.x

Is there a framework that is similar to [vert.x](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/05/vertx) (which is build on top of JVM) for .Net?

Comment: If you're looking to do web messaging, with some sort of persistent connection, and real-time push, check out SignalR.